# R xpathSApply: get node text without getting text from its children

Tags: r, xpath

I am trying to extract text from part of a website. The div node which contains the text also contains several children each with their own text or other content. However, I only want the text from the top node not from its children!

This is how the relevant page section looks like:

```
    <div class="body-text">
       <div id="other" class="other"></div>
       <div id="other2" class="other2"></div>
       <div id="other3" class="other3"> 
           <span>irrelevant text</span>
        </div>

       <h2>heading2</h2>

       -Text which I want to get. There are also text parts which are linked.

    </div>
```

This is my code which gets me the "messy" text. I tried `/text()`  but this will truncate my text whenever part of it is linked. So I cannot use it. I also tried something with `/div/node()[not(self::div)]` but have not managed to get it to work. Could anybody help?

```
webpage = getURL(url)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding='UTF-8')

body <- xpathSApply(pagetree, "//div[@class='body-text']", xmlValue)
```

Comment: *There are also text parts which are linked.* What does this mean?

Comment: @Iwburk, I meant that within the body text there are words or word sequences which contain/are a link, i.e. you can click on them and you are forwarded to another site. So when I use the `text()` option these words are not retrieved because they contain a `href` attribute, i.e. the text is incomplete.

Comment: I think I get your general requirement, but I have no idea what your reference to the `href` attribute is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 4):

**1) Posted example**

Try searching for nodes of `text()` or `a/text()` within the `body-text` division, removing any trivial nodes that only contain white space:

```
## input

Text <- '<div class="body-text">
       <div id="other" class="other"></div>
       <div id="other2" class="other2"></div>
       <div id="other3" class="other3"> 
           <span>irrelevant text</span>
        </div>
       <h2>heading2</h2>
       -Text which I want to get. There are also text parts which are linked.
    </div>'

library(XML)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(Text, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

## process it - xpth is the Xpath expression and xpathSApply() runs it

trim <- function(x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) # trim whitespace from start & end

xpth <- "( //div[@class='body-text']/text() | 
   //div[@class='body-text']/a/text() ) [ normalize-space() != '' ]"
txt <- trim(xpathSApply(pagetree, xpth, xmlValue))
```

The result is the following:

```
> txt
[1] "-Text which I want to get. There are also text parts which are linked."
```

**2) Example provided by poster in comments**.  Using this as `Text`

```
Text <- '<div class="body-text"> text starts here 
 <a class="footnote" href="link"> text continues here <sup>1</sup> </a> 
 and continues here</div>'
```

and repeating the above code we get:

```
> txt
[1] "text starts here"    "text continues here" "and continues here"
```

EDIT: Have modified the above based on comments by poster.  Main change was the xpath expression, `xpth` and final point which illustrates the same code with the example provided by the poster in the comments.

EDIT: Have moved the filtering out of whitespace-only nodes from R to Xpath.  This lengthens the Xpath expression a bit but eliminates the R Filter() step. Also simplified and reduced the presentation slightly.

Comment: Thanks for your help @G.Grothendieck! Unfortunately, this returns an incomplete text; as I mentioned above, there are parts of the text containing links (sorry if this was somewhat unclear!). So these will not be returned when I use `text()`. Is there any other way of telling `xpathSApply` NOT to get certain sub-nodes?

Comment: @Kat, It does not return incomplete text in the example posted. The entire text was returned. Please provide a *minimal* example which *reproduces* the problem.

Comment: OK, @G.Grothendieck, here is an example in which there is text within a link: `<div class="body-text"> text starts here <a class="footnote" href="link"> text continues here <sup>1</sup> </a> and continues here`
This is where text() fails to get the text.

Comment: @Kat - This back-and-forth could be avoided by providing a *representative* sample of your input and then, outside of that sample, showing *exactly* what text you expect to be selected.

Comment: Sorry @Iwburk, explaining this is rather complicated. Instead of creating examples, here the exact website from which I want to get the clean and complete article text: 
http://www.repubblica.it/esteri/2011/11/30/news/intelligence_israele_isfahan_sito_nucleare-25839461/index.html?ref=search
In the source code the text can be found in the section: `<div class="body-text">`

Comment: @Kat, I have modified the xpath expression and shown it using the posted example and the example in your comment.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks a lot! It doesn't even look so complicated, I think I can get it to work like this. Great!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible solutions to this problem, but, first, it's necessary to clarify which nodes you want to select. You say:

> I only want the text from the top node not from its children!

But this is not true! All of the element nodes found in the article text (e.g. `a`, `em,`, etc) *are themselves* children of the `body-text` `div`. What you really want to do is select all of the text found within a certain section of the `div`. Conveniently, [your source document](http://www.repubblica.it/esteri/2011/11/30/news/intelligence_israele_isfahan_sito_nucleare-25839461/index.html?ref=search) (linked in the comments above) contains comment nodes that **mark the start and end of the article**. They look like this:

```
<!-- inizio TESTO -->article text<!-- fine TESTO -->
```

In fact, you really only need the start marker, because there is no additional content after it.

#### Selecting text after the start marker

The following expression selects the desired nodes:

```
//div[@class='body-text']/comment()[.=' inizio TESTO ']/following::text()
```

Testing on the following stripped-down document:

```
<div class="body-text">
    <div class="fb-like-button" id="fb-like-head"></div>
    <h2><!-- inizio OCCHIELLO -->IRAN<!-- fine OCCHIELLO --></h2>
    <h1><!-- title -->"A Isfahan colpito sito nucleare"<br/>Londra annuncia azioni dure<!-- fine TITOLO --></h1>
    <h3><!-- summary -->Secondo il<em>Times</em>, fonti di intelligence...<br/><strong><br/></strong><!-- fine SOMMARIO --></h3>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar text...</div>
    <!-- inizio TESTO --><strong>TEHERAN</strong> - L'esplosione avvenuta 
    <a href="http://www.repubblica.it" class="footnote">lunedì scorso in Iran a Isfahan <sup>1</sup></a> avrebbe colpito un 
    sito nucleare. Lo hanno riferito fonti dell'intelligence israeliana al quotidiano britannico <em>The Times</em>, secondo le 
    quali alcune immagini satellitari "mostrano chiaramente colonne di fumo e la distruzione" di una struttura nucleare di Isfahan. 
    Sale, intanto, la tensione con la Gran Bretagna: dopo <a href="http://www.repubblica.it" class="footnote">l'assalto all'
    ambasciata britannica <sup>2</sup></a> ieri...<!-- fine TESTO -->
</div>
```

Returns the following text nodes:

```
[#text: TEHERAN]
[#text:  - L'esplosione avvenuta 
    ]
[#text: lunedì scorso in Iran a Isfahan ]
[#text: 1]
[#text:  avrebbe colpito un 
    sito nucleare. Lo hanno riferito fonti dell'intelligence israeliana al quotidiano britannico ]
[#text: The Times]
[#text: , secondo le 
    quali alcune immagini satellitari "mostrano chiaramente colonne di fumo e la distruzione" di una struttura nucleare di Isfahan. 
    Sale, intanto, la tensione con la Gran Bretagna: dopo ]
[#text: l'assalto all'
    ambasciata britannica ]
[#text: 2]
[#text:  ieri...]
[#text: 
]
```

This is a node-set, which you can iterate, etc. I do not know R, so I cannot provide those details.

#### Selecting text between the start and end markers

If there could be content after the end marker that should be excluded -- there isn't in the provided example -- then use the following expression:

```
//div[@class='body-text']//text()[preceding::comment()[.=' inizio TESTO '] and
                                  following::comment()[.=' fine TESTO ']]
```

#### Selecting text between the start and end markers (Kayessian Formula)

Note that the previous expression can be expressed more directly as the intersection of two node-sets: 1) all text nodes after the start marker and; 2) all text node before the end marker. There is a general formula for performing intersection in XPath 1.0:

```
$set1[count(.|$set2)=count($set2)]
```

The general idea here, in English, is that if you add an element from `$set1` into `$set2` and the size of `$set2` does not change, then that node must have already been in `$set2`. The set of all nodes from `$set1` for which this is the case is the intersection of `$set1` and `$set2`.

In your specific case:

```
$set1 = //div[@class='body-text']/comment()[.=' inizio TESTO ']/following::text()
$set2 = //div[@class='body-text']/comment()[.=' fine TESTO ']/preceding::text()
```

Putting it all together:

```
//div[@class='body-text']/comment()[.=' inizio TESTO ']/following::text()[
   count(.|//div[@class='body-text']/comment()[.=' fine TESTO ']/preceding::text())
     =
   count(//div[@class='body-text']/comment()[.=' fine TESTO ']/preceding::text())]
```

Comment: cool, @Iwburk, thanks for the input! This is def. very useful, also for further work. I didn't know you could select markers.